# Paperclip with Sinatra, AdapterRegistry-No handler errors

Tags: sinatra, paperclip

I have used the Paperclip gem with Rails before without any problem. Now I am trying to use it in the same way for uploading an image in a Sinatra Application with Active Record. But I get the following error when I press Submit:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError at /posts
No handler found for {:filename=>"194618-800.jpg", :type=>"image/jpeg", :name=>"post[image]", :tempfile=>#<File:/var/folders/5z/bl3r01mx0sbbljpfnryxjhqr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20131116-12697-jbv4i3>, :head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"194618-800.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"}
```

This is my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Paperclip::Glue

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tags

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:thumb => "150x150" }
end
```

And this is part of my form, where the image is selected:

```
<%= label :post, :image %>
<input type="file" name="post[image]"></input>
```

I havent forgot to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

I have also created and run the migration, using this line:

```
 add_attachment :posts, :image
```

I have been searching, but could not find a solution, so would appreciate if somebody gives me a hint. Thank you